# Let's encrypt для Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, letsencrypt, certbot

- создал поддомен: example.example.ru на хостинге
- прописал на нём А-запись с локальным IP

Пытаюсь создать через 
`certbot --standalone`
В итоге:

```
- The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example.example.ru
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://vh204.timeweb.ru/parking/?ref=example.example.ru
   [2a03:6f00:1::5c35:60d9]: "<!doctype html>\n<html class=\"no-js\"
   xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/html\">\n<head>\n    <script
   src=\"https://cdn.optimizely.com/js/4"
```

Как победить?

Comment: Сколько ждали после добавления A-записи?

Comment: Уже 17 часов прошло

Comment: Это больше установленного у домена TTL?

Comment: Естественно, я обращаюсь по этому домену и попадаю на апач который стоит на сервере. А вот сертификат не могу сделать

Comment: Ну ваше обращение в общем случае ничего не значит, потому что A-запись могла оказаться закэширована на том DNS-сервере, которым пользуется Let's Encrypt, оттого и спрашиваю про TTL (вдруг он был задан в целую неделю и вам придётся неделю ждать, всякое в мире бывает)

Comment: А example.ru действительно принадлежит вам? В смысле, вы легитимно можете в него добавлять записи, и они будут реально видны всему миру и Letsencrypt'у тоже?

Comment: Странно что в ошибке упоминается timeweb.ru. Никаких редиректов у вас не настроено?